# Expect fails for verifying inner HTML

Tags: jquery, selenium, testing, jasmine, protractor

For some reason my assert in protractor fails, what i'm trying to do is get the innerHTML (text) from an element:

```
var stuff = $('css').html();
```

expect(stuff).toBe("Inner HTML Text here");

I verified that the `$().html()` yields the text i desire on the console, what is wrong with my expect statement?

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'html'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getInnerHtml()`

```
expect($('.your-css').getInnerHtml()).toBe('your inner html');
```

http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getInnerHtml

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that whatever object "$" returns, it doesn't have an "html" method.

If you expect "$" to be a reference to jQuery then try using "jQuery" explicitly e.g.

```
var stuff = jQuery('css').html();
```

Also, I'm not sure if the selector in the above statement is your actual selector, if so, it's looking for a "css" element which doesn't seem right. You might want to look at that.